# How to add authorization header in POSTMAN environment?

Tags: postman, web-api-testing

I'm testing bunch of API calls using POSTMAN. Instead of adding authorization header to each request, can I make it as a part of POSTMAN environment? So, I don't have to pass it with every request.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, you can do this through Postman by assigning your header as an environment variable, let's say `authorization`, as follow:

[image: Authorization header]

then set you environment variable with its value as follow:

[image: Environment variable]

Comment: ^ Agree with above comment, I came here looking for how to add a header to every request without having to edit each request manually. I have 58 requests in the suite I'm currently working on, and a new requirement that each one send an Authorzation header that wasn't present before.

Answer (score 22):

In contemporary releases of Postman, you can just set your auth on the collection (or folder), and have every request inherit it (which I believe new requests do by default).

[image: Edit collection menu]

[image: Set your auth on the authorization tab]

Comment: How do you add this after the collection has already been created?  I dont find a way to edit the collection and add auth.  It only appears to exist when you first create a collection.

Comment: Updated with screenshots showing how to do this in the Postman UI

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Also, this, if you want to set custom Auth header(s), instead of the normal, selectable ones: https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/collection/9215231-ef055751-7385-45b4-a6f9-91bbd1c47fa5

Answer (score 5):

postman usually remembers your key-value pairs you send in header. So there is no need to add headers each request. Anyway you can configure a "Preset" with your auth token.
[image]

Comment: yea but what if you need different preset to each environment

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but we use a link-based API that requires auth headers on each request. If you go to `Postman > Preferences > General` and enable `Retain headers when clicking on links`, Postman will pass through your auth headers to the child links.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't wait here is a work around I just made:

1. Export your collection (data format v2.1)
2. Open firefox , dev tools, scratch pad
3. Paste the code below
4. Replace the header information with your header
5. Replace the var a with your contents of the exported .json file
6. Run the script
7. The copy(b) command will put the new data with in your clipboard
8. In postman, click import > Paste Raw Text > Import > as a copy.
9. Verify your requests have your header, and run it :)

```js
var myHeader = {
  "key": "X-Client-DN",
  "value": "{{Postman-DN}}",
  "description": "The User's DN Interacting with the system."
};

function addHeader(obj, header) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('request')) {
    obj.request.header.push(myHeader)
  }
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('item')) {
    obj.item.forEach(function(element) {
      element = addHeader(element, header);
    });
  }
  return obj;
}

var a = {
  "item": [{}, {
    "request": {
      "header": []
    }
  }, {
    "item": [{
      "request": {
        "header": []
      }
    }]
  }]
}

var b = addHeader(a, myHeader);
console.log(JSON.stringify(b, null, 2))

// Might have to run copy manually on console
//copy(b);
```