# Test Django REST Framework Login Protected API using Postman?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I need to test REST API using postman. API is build using Django REST Framework. Only login user can get access to API. I am not able to find how I can send login credentials using postman.

```
class ApiMemberGroupNameList(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
        RequiredOrgPermission,
        RequiredOrgStaffMemberPermission)

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        hash = kwargs.get('hash')
        member_obj = get_object_or_404(Member.objects.filter(org__hash=hash, pk=pk))
        return Response(GroupListSerializer(member_obj.groups.all(), many=True).data)
```

Comment: Send the login details to your login url with a post request via Postman. I dont know how your authentication works, but your API should return some sort of access token, which you can probably use to access the rest of the API

Comment: Continuing on from @Snackoverflow, then you should be able to use the access token using something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539609/how-to-add-authorization-header-in-postman-environment

Comment: Authentication is not the token base. It is normal Django authentication using username and password. May we can send cookies info in a way the browser sends to the server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Basic Auth` in POSTMAN. Refer to this screenshot:

[image]

You could change the `HTTP Methods`, `URLs`, `Data Payload`(under `Body` tab) etc in the POSTMAN console

**UPDATE-1**

After your comments, I tried to recreated the problem.What I did was:

1. created a view

   ```
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
    from rest_framework.response import Response

    class MySampleView(APIView):
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

        def get(self, request):
            return Response(data={"status": True})
   ```
2. Added to `urls.py`

   ```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^mysampleview/$', MySampleView.as_view())
    ]
   ```

And my POSTMAN response are below:

[Authorization Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THvRn.png)

[Header Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFmnH.png)

**My conclusion**

You may enter wrong credentials, or something else. I would suggest you open a new POSTMAN tab and repeat the procedure, also try to login Django admin using the same credential which is already used in POSTMAN.

Comment: I have tried this one but it's not working. Normally Django varifies authenticated a user through session and cookies.

Comment: Can you add your respective `view.py`?

Comment: Peter I have added view in question.

Comment: seems like you only added `permission_classes` in `views`. Did you add any other authentication methods in settings?

Comment: No, I am not using any other authentication model in settings. Even I remove permission classes except for IsAuthenticated. I still face the same issue.

Comment: I got the response forbidden

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Basic Authentification to test Django REST API, it must be allowed in Django REST Framework settings:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
...
```